# trying to have 1 trade per session difined

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have written the following script, but getting 1 alert per bar while in a session, I copied it as per a previous post but cant see where I have gone wrong

```
var traded_today = false

sessionInput1 = input.session("1800-2200", group = " Trading Session")
timeZone1 = input.string("GMT+10", title="Time Zone", group = "Trading Session")
InSession1(sess) => na(time(timeframe.period, sess)) == false

IsInSession1 = InSession1(sessionInput1)
is_new_session1 = not IsInSession1[1] and IsInSession1

traded_today := is_new_session1 ? false : traded_today  // If it is a new session, reset the variable. Keep its value otherwise

Buy = IsInSession1 and BuyCond1 and BuyCond2 and BuyCond3 and not traded_today

if (Buy)
    traded_today := true
    alert("Buy Limit " + syminfo.ticker + " at " + str.tostring(sessionHighPrice, "0.000") + "\n TP " + str.tostring(Buy_TP, "0.000") + "\n SL " + str.tostring(Buy_SL, "0.000") + "\n TimeStamp " + str.tostring(timenow + 10), alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are using `input.session()` in combination with `time()` you have to include the Timezone, or all will be offset. You where using `input.string()` for this, which is good. but you didn't used it at all.

Your function needed to be edited, cause of two reasons.

1. I explained already
2. the commands in that function didn't match the description in the [document](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_time-0).

the relevant changes looks like this...

```
InSession1(sess, tz) => not na(time(timeframe.period, sess, tz)) ? true : false
IsInSession1 = InSession1(sessionInput1, timeZone1)
```

**What did I change?..**

I added a second variable to the function, which is used to determine the timezone you are in. Then I changed your `if` statement in that function. To be honest it looks weird and you should have a look at the [syntax](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#kw_if) again.
I changed that line into `?:` which you can read what it does [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_?:).

While we are at a debugging state I will recommend you to use the new `log.*()` which makes it much more easy to [debug](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_log.info) code.

**Addition...**

It seems to me you want to use alerts and you use many conversions into string. For alerts using buy & sell orders you should go for `strategy.entry(alert_message = "")` and `strategy.exit(alert_* = "")`. For the conversion thingy you can do it all at once with `str.format()` explained [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_str.format).